# Using equation of a line to find infinitely many different solutions of $ x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

By taking a line through $(1, 0)$ it is possible to find a point where the line crosses another point of $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$. Then we could take a line that passes through the that point and find another point which intersects $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$. We can repeat this as many times as we like. My question is, why does this procedure to infintly many different solutions to $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$? I am only looking for integer solutions. Thank you.

Edit: Here's a full question I'm working on if something is unclear. I'm struggling with part e).
[image]

Comment: I don't understand. How do you know that you will get infinitely many integer solutions?

Comment: I need to prove that I get infinitly many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The Diophantine equation $x^2-2y^2=1$ has infinitely many integer solutions, see [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation). We can start with $(x_1,y_1)=(3,2)$, and then set $ x_k + y_k \sqrt 2 = (x_1 + y_1 \sqrt 2)^k$ for $k\ge 1$.

How to use Pell's equation for square-triangular numbers, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number). It follows immediately that there are infinitely many different square-triangular numbers.

Comment: I know this method, but I am trying to prove that the method with line works also.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I am not familiar with those methods yet, that's why I'm trying to prove it only using the things I'm given.

Comment: The geometric method also immediately gives you infinitely many solutions to $x^2-2y^2=1$, and then you only need an easy algebraic formula relating it to square-triangular numbers, i.e. $t_k=(P_{2k}+P_{2k-1}-1)/2$.

Comment: But does it give infinitly many integer solutions?

Comment: It gives *all* rational and integer solutions, hence infinitely many (which we know anyway, see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since we have a line, then it is on the form $y=ax+b$. This line pass through $(1,0)$, so the affine function became $y=ax-a=a(x-1)$. It remains you to insert the equation in $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$. The last step is trivial.

Comment: Namely that there is no infinite solutions. The exercise puts a line through a circle of radius 1. It can therefore be 0, 1 or 2 solutions.